# Formula in Google Spreadsheet to display the value of one cell in another cell where the number of columns between the cells is a controlled variable?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, worksheet-function

How do I create a formula in Google Spreadsheet which will display the value of one cell (eg cell A2) in another cell (eg C3) where the number of columns between the cells (n) is a controlled variable (in this example "2")?

Use case: I have a cash-flow model broken down by weeks in columns and want to show revenue 'n' number of weeks after deal has been signed, where I can manipulate one cell (representing the value of 'n') to see the impact on the model.

Answer (score 6):

You use `INDIRECT` for this.

```
=INDIRECT("A"&n)
```

Where `n` is your variable. So, if `n = 2`, you get `A2`. If `n = 3`, you get `A3`.

EDIT: To reflect the change I made in the spreadsheet, here's the formula I used instead:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(6:6,1,COLUMN()-$B$14-1)*$B$13,0)
```

Comment: Can you pls clarify using dummy spreadsheet at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiHb61ium2yHdGVMVWJaNVhUTm9OZjZIVzlnV3VuUmc&usp=sharing . In the example here, revenue comes in 4 weeks after contract signed (hard coded). What I want to be able to do is enter a number in cell "A1" to reflect the amount of weeks revenue should come after contract signed which will affect which column the revenue appears in. ie. if n=2 then D7 would be 10000 and E7 would be 20000.

Comment: @Isaac sorry for the delay; I didn't get a notification somehow for your comment :(. I have edited your spreadsheet to do that and I've used INDEX instead since I think it might be more appropriate. Note that I had to press Ctrl+E on the cell with the little corner for google spreadsheet to display all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working on a character spreadsheet and the solution I got was to use offset.
The format is =offset(a,b,c)
where a stands for the cell you want as your placeholder, in your example it would be a2.
where b contains the value which will be moved over for rows (I actually have it targeting another cell so when I "level up" I can just change one box and everything dependent on it updates).
Where c contains the value to move over in columns.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en